# Xlsxwriter: Is it possible to do East Asian Language Vertical Text on a cell?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to create an Excel file using Xlsxwriter. The language written to each cell is Japanese, and I would like to set the cell's text to be vertical text as decribed [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_global_experience/2010/03/24/east-asian-text-layout-features-in-office-2010/).

Is this possible using Xlsxwriter?

Comment: For those not familiar with Japanese vertical text, kindly see: http://digitalmofo.com/wp-content/plugins/rss-poster/cache/8bd84_svg-text-vertical.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, for any text, using the `set_rotation/rotation` cell format method/property and the special rotation angle of 270 for vertical text ([docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_rotation)).

Here is a Python2 example in an UTF-8 encoded file:

```
# _*_ coding: utf-8


import xlsxwriter

workbook    = xlsxwriter.Workbook('unicode_vertical.xlsx')
worksheet   = workbook.add_worksheet()

text_format = workbook.add_format({'rotation': 270})

worksheet.write('B2', u'こんにちは世界', text_format)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

For Python3 you don't need the `coding` directive or `u''`. See the Xlsxwriter [Unicode with Python2](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_unicode_python2.html) and [Unicode with Python3](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_unicode_python3.html) examples.

Comment: This is great. Let me give this a try. Your answer is quite thorough!